# Make a Spark TitleWindow modal without using much AS3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, mxml, flash-builder

I want to be able to show a Spark TitleWindow container as a modal without having to construct it by code via AS3. I tried creating the TitleWindow before-hand manually by dragging and resizing it around and adding objects, etc then hiding it. Then on a button, I set the called function to the ones below:

```
public function doPopup():void {
    testWindow.visible = true;
    PopUpManager.addPopUp(testWindow, this, true);
}
```

Unfortunately, this only shows **testWindow** but not as a modal. I want it to be like this so that I can freely resize and design the layout of my TitleWindow and only have to call some function to show it as a modal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the reason you are seeing this behavior is because your TitleWindow (that you've declared within the mxml of the parent container) is already added to the stage even though it is set as not visible.  A workaround you could try is to call this.removeElement(testWindow) in a creation complete handler for the parent container.  That will get it off the stage so the PopUpManager can add it later properly.

Having said that, I would recommend putting your TitleWindow into a separate mxml file and instantiate it using the PopUpManager.  It's cleaner that way and you can still use the design mode to lay it out as you see fit.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but I'm quite new to Flex and Flash Builder all the same. So when you say "I would recommend putting your TitleWindow into a separate mxml file and instantiate it using the PopUpManager.", what did you mean by putting it into a seperate mxml file and instantiate it? Do I put it on a new component and call the component using PopUpManager? Or do I put the TitleWindow AND the PopUpManager call into a component?

Comment: I meant create a new MXML file, let's call it "MyTitleWindow", that uses TitleWindow as its base (which you select in the dialog when creating the file.)  Then in your main component you can instantiate your custom title window (var window:MyTitleWindow = new MyTitleWindow()), then add display it (PopUpManager.addPopUp(window, this, true)).

Comment: Okay, I got it to work but for some odd reason, even if I set the horizontalCenter and the verticalCenter of the TitleWindow class I made, it keeps popping up at the top-left most part of the web application. How do I make it appear on the center?

Comment: After calling PopUpManager.addPopUp, call PopUpManager.centerPopUp.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Cairngorm 3 Popup library :

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/HowToUseCairngormPopup